# joomla - SEO settings and mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo, joomla

I'm using Joomla 1.5.14 and I configured SEO as in the following image

[image]

Now I need to map a few old URL to the new site

let's say that I need to map htp://mysite/old.html to the new Joomla page

> `http://mysite/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=32&Itemid=70`

I added in my .htaccess file the following

```
RewriteRule ^old\.html$ index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=32&Itemid=70  #works!!
```

this works fine, but if I use the SEF URL in .htaccess (let's say the above page can be reached with htp://mysite/contacts.html), I obtain a 404 error

```
RewriteRule ^old\.html$ contacts.html   #this does not work
```

**Now the question:**

Is it possible use SEF URLs in RewriteRule? where am I wrong?

thank you in advance

stefano

Comment: Remember, StackOverflow is for developing questions, for server configuration follow http://serverfault.com/

Comment: ok (BTW: I saw a lot of question here about mod_rewrite, but was not able to find a solution for my question)

Comment: This is fine IMO, it's programming of sorts anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is because Apache rewrites `old.html` to a page that doesn't actually exist, but rewritten in a different rule.

If you truly want to "rewrite" - in other words, have the page stay as `old.html` in the browser - then you don't need to do anything.

However to avoid duplicate content it's probably better to do a 301 redirect:

```
Redirect 301 old.html http://yoursite.com/contact.html
```

(You may need a forward slash at the front of `old.html`)

Comment: thanks!
I think you're right about Apache rewriting old.html to an unexistent page (even if mod_rewrite should "run" before joomla stuff).

Redirect works, even if it adds a roundtrip, and I don't know if it has any SEO counter-indication

Comment: It's generally better for SEO as far as I'm aware, since you're giving Google etc one URL per piece of content, and telling it to count links for `old.html` as if they were links for `contact.html`